# Caroufredsel filter not working

Tags: jquery, filter, show-hide, caroufredsel

I need a Caroufredsel which I must filter (hide/unhide elements) when I check/uncheck certain checkboxes, I try adding/removing a class to the item and set the caroufredsel items.filter configuration to that class through jquery but it doesn't work, this is what I did:

```
 $("#myc").carouFredSel({
        circular: true,
        items: {
            visible: 4,
            filter: ".i-visible"
        },
        auto: false,
        prev: "#a_prev",
        next: "#a_next"
    });
```

and when I click in each checkbox:

```
 $('.mycheckbox').click(function () {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $(this).parent().children("#myc").children(".item").each(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("i-visible");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue. I tried setting the items option 'visible' equal to 'variable' and that seems to work.